# How to auto-close app open ads after splash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I placed an ad of the type: "app-open" admob.
This advertisement is not accepted by the App Store except in one case:
That there is a splash for the application, and that the advertisement appears above the splash and ends with the end of the splash.

> For example: Here I set the time to run the ad after the splash
> appears

```
  /** LifecycleObserver methods */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    public void onStart() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showAdIfAvailable();
            }
        }, 1000);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
    }
```

> Here is the total splash timing:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (go) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash_Activity.this, Home_main.class));
                finish(); 
                //If you delete the finish also the splash appears after exiting the application, how can this process be transferred to the advertisement
            }
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

**So if you are asking where is the problem:**
The problem is: If you do not close the ad, it will close automatically at the end of the time of the splash, **but** when you exit the application you find the ad and you need to close it.

**What I need:**
It is an automatic closure and a finish for the advertisement when the splash timer ends.

> AppOpenManager.clss

```
  /** Prefetches App Open Ads. */
    public class AppOpenManager implements LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    
    
    
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
        private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "MY APP AD UNIT ID";
        private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
        private long loadTime = 0;
    
        private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;
        private Activity currentActivity;
        private static boolean isShowingAd = false;
    
        private final GlobalVar home_main;
    
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public AppOpenManager(GlobalVar home_main) {
            this.home_main = home_main;
            this.home_main.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
            ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        }
    
        public static void showAdIfAvailable(FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback) {
        }
    
        /** LifecycleObserver methods */
        @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
        public void onStart() {
    
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showAdIfAvailable();
    
                }
            }, 1000);
    
    
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
        }
    
        /** Shows the ad if one isn't already showing. */
        public void showAdIfAvailable() {
            // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
            // and an ad is available.
            if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");
    
                FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                        new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                                AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                                isShowingAd = false;
                                fetchAd();
                            }
    
                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}
    
                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                isShowingAd = true;
                            }
                        };
    
                appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
                appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);
    
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
                fetchAd();
            }
        }
    
    
        /**
         * Request an ad
         */
        public void fetchAd() {
    
    
            // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
            if (isAdAvailable()) {
                return;
            }
    
            loadCallback =
                    new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                        /**
                         * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
                         *
                         * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
                            AppOpenManager.this.loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                        }
    
                        /**
                         * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
                         *
                         * @param loadAdError the error.
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                            // Handle the error.
                        }
    
                    };
            AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
            AppOpenAd.load(
                    home_main, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
                    AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
        }
        // We will implement this below.
    
    
        /**
         * Creates and returns ad request.
         */
        private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
            return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        }
    
        /**
         * Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown.
         */
        public boolean isAdAvailable() {
            return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
            currentActivity = activity;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            currentActivity = activity;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            currentActivity = null;
        }
        /** Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
        private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
            long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - this.loadTime;
            long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
            return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
        }
    }
```

Comment: **No**, you can't close an ad automatically. But you can stop further code execution until user closes the ad using a callback listener. If you think it may solve your issue, I can post sample code here.